# "progressive" web site loading

Tags: javascript, css, user-interface, web

I'm looking for a way to generate a kind of a "progressive" page loading effect that you can see when reloading for example Linkedin :

[image]

It loads instantly, and is replaced by real content when it loads.
I've seen it already on a lot of web sites, so I'm guessing there's a name for it and a right approach / js framework that does that :)

Comment: Probably uses Ajax. Loads the "frame" immediately, then fetches the data and plugs it in.

Comment: Pretty much all JS frameworks which can handle AJAX are able to do this. I don't believe it has a particular name besides AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in here it's the transition between your "Not loaded content" and your "real content".

For your "Not loaded content" you can simply put some empty divs, thumnails, or even just images. Even more easy but risk, an entire image of your website "not loaded at all".

But then you have to find the way to disapear that stuff and fade in your "real content".

You can practice, with the jquery animate functions "fadein" and "fadeout" or use some libraries like [Animate.cc](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/), but the difficult thing is put the 2 contents in the same place (index-z css property).

Instead of all this search for a library that do this.